# How to make one column dependent from another column in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am creating a new database table, and I want to make one column be dependent on another column.

I have tried to add some check constraint

```
CREATE TABLE borrower (
   borrower_salary_id INT REFERENCES borrower_salary(id),
   borrower_additional_income BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   borrower_additional_income_amount INT,
   borrower_previous_loans BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   borrower_previous_loans_payment_delay BOOLEAN,
);
```

if and only if borrower_additional_income is true, borrower_additional_income_amount should contain some values how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check` constraint looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE borrower (
   borrower_salary_id INT REFERENCES borrower_salary(id),
   borrower_additional_income BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   borrower_additional_income_amount INT,
   borrower_previous_loans BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   borrower_previous_loans_payment_delay BOOLEAN,
   CHECK ( (borrower_additional_income AND  borrower_additional_income_amount IS NOT NULL) OR
           (NOT borrower_additional_income AND borrower_additional_income_amount IS NULL )
         )
);
```

Or simplified to:

```
   CHECK ( borrower_additional_income =  (borrower_additional_income_amount IS NOT NULL)
         )
);
```

The question, though, is why have a flag?  Why not just check whether or not `borrower_additional_income_amount` is or is not `NULL`?

Comment: Can be simplified to `CHECK (borrower_additional_income = (borrower_additional_income_amount IS NOT NULL))`.

Comment: @TheImpaler and what if I have   `borrower_loan_amount_id INT REFERENCES loan_amount(id),
   borrower_exact_loan_amount INT DEFAULT 0`  I want to   borrower_exact_loan_amount  to cointain value other than 0 if and only if  borrower_loan_amount_id is equal to 5, then i should do like that  `CHECK ( borrower_exact_loan_amount =  (borrower_loan_amount_id = 5)
         )`?

Comment: @CreatingDED . . . You can check for a particular value.